# VBA Loop one sheet to the next

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have two sheets, "Data 1" where I have all my data, "Schedule 1" where it is a form that needs to be filled out. 
What I want to do is go through each row in "Data 1" and place the value of column E into column C in "Schedule 1" sheet then save just the "Schedule 1" sheet. Then repeat the process until all lines are done. This is what I have so far, I am a bit stuck on what to do next.

```
   Public Sub CopyRows()
        Dim SaveSheet As Worksheet
        Sheets("Data1").Select
        ' Find the last row of data
        FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        ' Loop through each row
        For x = 2 To FinalRow

        'Code here. How can I go through all the rows in "Data 1" and place the value of column E into column C in "Schedule 1"

     'Save just the sheet
    Set SaveSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Data1)

     SaveSheet.SaveAs FilePath, xlXMLSpreadsheet
     SaveSheet.Name = SheetName 'I would like to put the name of values in Column A from "Data 1" sheet


        Next x
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can't save a worksheet. Only workbooks can be saved, and when you save a workbook all sheets in it are saved at the same time.

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code sheet, VBE's *Intellisense* will show you that the `SaveAs` method isn't available for the variable `SaveSheet` which is declared As Worksheet. For each object you can only use its own methods and properties which are listed by *Intellisense* if you enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clear on how you want to copy the data, but this should give you a start:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRows()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsSchedule As Worksheet
    Dim FinalRow As Long, x As Long, wbNew As Workbook, nm

    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data1")
    Set wsSchedule = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule 1")

    FinalRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To FinalRow

        'copy over some data
        nm = wsData.Cells(x, "E").Value
        wsSchedule.Range("C1").Value = nm
        wsSchedule.Copy 'create a new workbook with the copied sheet
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook 'the new workbook with the copied sheet
        'save the new workbook in an "exports" subfolder in the same
        '   folder as this workbook
        wbNew.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Exports\" & nm & ".xlsx"
        wbNew.Close False

    Next x

End Sub
```